# Adding activityindicatorin alertVIew

Tags: iphone, uialertview

I want to add a activity indicator in alertView.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do by this -

```
    UIAlertView *alertview = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"title" message:@"\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130.0f, 50.0f, 20.0f, 20.0f)];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [alertview addSubview:activityIndicator];
    [alertview show];
    [alertview release];
    [activityIndicator release];
```

Comment: You also need to release activityIndicator.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIAlertView *alert;



alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Configuring Preferences\nPlease Wait..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];
[alert show];

UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

// Adjust the indicator so it is up a few pixels from the bottom of the alert
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height - 50);
[indicator startAnimating];
[alert addSubview:indicator];
[indicator release];
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the tutorial [here](http://kwigbo.tumblr.com/post/394670170/iphone-sdk-uialertview-with-activity-indicator)